# "Missing parameter type" in for-comprehension when overloading flatMap

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I wrote my own Either-like monad class called `Maybe` with either a value or an error object inside it. I want objects of this class to combine with `Future`, so that I can turn a `Maybe[Future[T], E]]` into a `Future[Maybe[T, E]]`. Therefore I implemented two `flatMap` methods:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future

sealed abstract class Maybe[+E, +V] {

  def map[W](f: V ⇒ W ): Maybe[E, W] = this match {
    case Value(v) ⇒ Value(f(v))
    case Error(_) ⇒ this.asInstanceOf[Error[E, W]]
  }

  def flatMap[F >: E, W](f: V ⇒ Maybe[F, W]): Maybe[F, W] = this match {
    case Value(v) ⇒ f(v)
    case Error(_) ⇒ this.asInstanceOf[Error[F, W]]
  }

  def flatMap[W](f: V ⇒ Future[W]): Future[Maybe[E, W]] = this match {
    case Value(v) ⇒ f(v).map(Value(_))
    case Error(_) ⇒ Future.successful(this.asInstanceOf[Error[E, W]])
  }
}

final case class Value[+E, +V](value: V) extends Maybe[E, V]    
final case class Error[+E, +V](error: E) extends Maybe[E, V]
```

However, when I use the for comprehension to combine a `Maybe` and a `Future` which holds another `Maybe` the Scala compiler gives me the error message `missing parameter type` at the line of the outer generator:

```
def retrieveStreet(id: String): Future[Maybe[String, String]] = ...

val outerMaybe: Maybe[String, String] = ...

val result = for {
      id ← outerMaybe // error message "missing parameter type" here!
      street ← retrieveStreet(id)
    } yield street
```

But when instead of using `for` I call the `flatMap`and `map`methods explicitly, it works:

```
val result2 =
  outerMaybe.flatMap( id => retrieveStreet(id) )
            .map( street => street )
```

(I also get this error message when I try to combine a `Maybe` with another `Maybe` in a for comprehension.)

So the questions are:

1. Shouldn't these two alternatives behave exactly the same? Why does the compiler figure out the correct `flatMap` method to call, when calling `flatMap` explicitly?
2. Since apparently the compiler is confused by the two `flatMap` implementations, is there a way to tell it (by a type specification anywhere) which one should be called in the for comprehension?

I am using Scala 2.11.8 in Eclipse.

Comment: I am surprised, your flatMap overload even compiles (most probably, scalac is just confused, and shows you a wrong error. Try removing the for comprehension and seeing if it compiles then).

Comment: The reason I think it should not compile is that both versions of `flatMap` have the same signature after type erasure. That's not allowed. I don't think it is possible to do what you want here,  but will be happy to find out if someone can prove me wrong.

Comment: @Dima If the problem is the same signature, why does the alternative notation (`flatMap`/`map`) work?

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a comprehensive answer, but running it through `scalac -Xprint:parser`, I can tell you that the 2 alternatives actually desugar slightly differently, there's a good chance this is the source of your issue.

```
val result1 = outerMaybe
  .flatMap(((id) => retrieveStreet(id)
  .map(((street) => street))));

val result2 = outerMaybe
  .flatMap(((id) => retrieveStreet(id)))
  .map(((street) => street))
```